# How to create DSN

Tags: sql-server, dsn

I got a project source code from internet having below specifications:

Environment:

- Visual Studio .NET 2002
- Visual Basic.NET
- SQL Server 2000

Now I need to create DSN with consumer database that exist in folder. Please help me how can I create this ?

I have to configure this for Windows 8 and 10.

And do I need to install SQL Server as well to use this project ?

Comment: Are you ***really*** using SQL Server 2000??? I'm pretty sure that won't even run on Windows 8 *or* 10, SQL Server 2000 has been End of Life for almost 8 years! You ***need*** to get that upgrade path sorted out ASAP, and it's going to be an absolute pain now that you've left it so late.

Comment: Give the age of the source code and underlying technology stack, I suggest you find another source for your need or start from scratch. The world has changed much in the last 20 years.

Comment: Windows key => Search ODBC. Open ODBC datasources and add a DSN there (under system or user). You'll still need the correct drivers for the DSN and those are long gone. Since you are running SQL Server 2000.

Comment: @PrebenHuybrechts I need to create DSN with MS Access database file (.mdb) then I still need to install drivers ?

Comment: @Larnu  I need to create DSN with MS Access database file (.mdb) then I still need to install drivers ?

Comment: What does the question have to do the Microsoft Access here, @Mohsin ? You have tagged [tag:sql-server]